# Is safe to route a rmii (txd0 txd1) track under resistors?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, esp32, rmii

I'm creating a PCB to connect an ESP32 to a PHY (lan8720) and I want do route a trace under some resistors. Is there any problem (crosstalk) doing this? The trace is txd0 (txd- on picture) under the resistor txd1.

[image]

Comment: Worst for cross-talk: close, parallel tracks.  Better: perpendicular tracks.  Best: tracks far away from each other.

Answer (score 3):

> so there is any problem (crosstalk) doing this ?

Depends on what layer those traces are on, if they are on adjacent layers, there will be some cross capacitance in the pico-femto farad range. Take your schematic and see what adding in very small capacitors will do to the signal and then see if it will be a problem (probably not)

If there is a ground layer in between on the PCB stackup, then there will be negligible crosstalk.